# Is there a way to use Tor to download apps for Windows 8 from the Windows Store anonymously?

Tags: anonymity, configuration, windows

Is there a way to use Tor to download apps for Windows 8 from the Windows Store anonymously?  The Windows Store uses its own customized app for access and apparently isn't accessible from normal browsers.  Is there a way I could redirect access attempts by the Windows Store app into Tor?  Or, is there a way to use the Windows Store from Torbrowser, without involving the Windows Store app?

Comment: Set up a global proxy to the socks port tor runs. More info: https://superuser.com/questions/397577/how-to-setup-a-proxy-for-modern-ui-aka-metro-apps-in-windows-8

Comment: @David Can you convert your comment in an answer and provide details how to set a proxy?